# Is it possible to import an autocad feature to a feature layer without exporting to .shp/.dwg

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, arcgis-9.3, import, autocad

Does anyone know if it is possible to import a feature (point, line or polygon) drawn in Autocad directly to a feature layer in ArcMap, so in essence a "feature sucker", rather then exporting the feature to a shp or dwg then importing into ArcMap then copying the feature into the correct feature class.

The datatype that I want to target  is a feature class on ArcSDE (9.2).

Versions are ArcGIS 9.3.1 and AutoCAD 2011.

Comment: you are a bit vague. please specify the data type you want to put the feature into. a feature layer can be many data sources in arcmap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [autocad Map3d](http://usa.autodesk.com/autocad-map-3d/) you can connect ogr, or shape/sde/oracle/sql datasources.
With this functionality you can create objects directly in autocad that are in turn "put" into the source you specify.
If your version truly is autocad then the fdo option is not there (Map product line only).
If you upgrade or see differently you can check out more about FDO on the [osgeo](http://fdo.osgeo.org/) website.
Autocad map and Civil have FDO built in.
You can connect native formats and edit directly depending on the [provider](http://fdo.osgeo.org/OSProviderOverviews.html).
If you are not on a map product, The answers from Jakub and BicycleDude are both viable.

Comment: Didnt know that could be done. I'll investigate what version we have. Thanks.

Comment: the version will determine which FDO version you can run. The type will have to be map3d or civil3d. see answer for more.

Answer (score 2):

You can Load Features into an existing feature class from a DWG or a DXF file.  In catalog, right click on a Feature Class --> Load --> Load Data --> Select Input Data --> go trough all steps to define field mapping, etc. if needed.

You can also load multiple data layers of the same geometry type by adding them into the "List of SOurce Data to Load" on the first step of the Simple Data Loader dialog.

Answer (score 1):

You could look at the FME Desktop and the ArcGIS Desktop Data Interoperability extension. I believe this will do it. You may be lucky and some of this functionality is also in the Data Interporability toolkit.